# How to paste a string into specific line using nmap for key-binding?

Tags: key-bindings, neovim

Basically what I want to do is running this key-binding:

```
nmap <Leader>= :[x digits]pu<CR>
```

My mapleader **Leader** is a space.

With the code above I want to paste the current string I have in the clipboard but by specifying the number line where I want to paste it.
For example, If I want to paste the current clipboard into the third line I would type:

```
:3pu
```

Or by using a shorcut with `nmap`:

```
nmap <Leader>= :3pu<CR>
```

So when I press <kbd>space</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> the vim command `:3pu` will be executed.

Nevertheless, what I want is to specify the number (with one digit or more) by using the `nmap`. For example, if I press <kbd>3</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> then this command `:3pu` should run or If I press <kbd>14</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> then
this command should run: `14pu`.

Is it possible to do that by using `nmap`? I've seen about using something like this:

```
nmap [Number]<Leader>= :pu<CR>
```

but I don't know how to detect what number I've pressed. I've  read about using `v.count` though I was not able to detect with that the pressed number and add it before `pu`.

Btw, I'm using `neovim` for this (in case this matters).

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: @D.BenKnoble thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works:

```
nnoremap <leader>= :<C-u>execute v:count 'put'<cr>
```

(you can probably also use `<Cmd>` instead of `:<C-u>`).

Comment: Thanks so much!!  This really worked :D .